# unpack requires a string argument of length 92 python

Tags: python, client-server, pack

I need your help to solve a problem in my code that I do not know what causes it the error I get on my client is:

> ```
> unpack_string = struct.unpack(fmt, data)
> struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 92
> ```

I would be happy if you could help me understand why this is happening and how I can fix it

Server code -

```
import socket
import struct
import os
import subprocess
import commands

def cmd_output(command):
    return commands.getstatusoutput(command)

def main():

serv_soc = socket.socket()
serv_soc.bind(("127.0.0.1", 50111))
serv_soc.listen(1)
client_soc, client_address = serv_soc.accept()
option = 1

while(option != 5):
    client_data = client_soc.recv(1024)
    unpack = struct.unpack('Bh', client_data)
    option = unpack[0]
    print option    

    if(option == 1):
        pass 

    elif(option == 2):
        pass

    elif(option == 3):
        fmt = "%ds" % unpack[1]
        new_data = client_soc.recv(1024)
        command = struct.unpack(fmt, new_data)
        out = cmd_output(command[0])
        print len(out[1])
        print out
        pack = struct.pack('Bh', 3, len(out[1]))
        print pack
        client_soc.send(pack)
        fmt = "%ds" % len(out[1])
        print out[1]
        pack_string = struct.pack(fmt, out[1])
        client_soc.send(pack)

    elif(option == 4):
        pass

serv_soc.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Client code -

```
import socket
import struct

def main():

# Open socket
my_soc = socket.socket()
my_soc.connect(("127.0.0.1", 50111))

option = input("Enter option:")
while (option != 5):

    if(option == 1):
       pass

    elif(option == 2):
        pass

    elif(option == 3):
        command = raw_input("Enter command: ")
        pack = struct.pack('Bh', 3, len(command))
        my_soc.send(pack)
        fmt = "%ds" % len(command)
        pack_string = struct.pack(fmt, command)
        my_soc.send(pack_string)

    elif(option == 4):
        pass

    data = my_soc.recv(1024)
    unpack = struct.unpack('Bh', data)
    fmt = "%ds" % unpack[1]
    data = my_soc.recv(1024)
    unpack_string = struct.unpack(fmt, data) # Here Is the Problem 
    print unpack_string
    option = input("Enter option:")

my_soc.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem occurs when the server returns his output to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server code, `pack_string` was prepared but `pack` was sent instead:

```
        pack_string = struct.pack(fmt, out[1])
        client_soc.send(pack)
```